# How to iterate through the list in aerospike using golang?

Tags: go, aerospike

I am using the list data type (http://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/cdt-list.html
) in aerospike using a golang client. I can use the ListInsertOp (https://godoc.org/github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-go#ListInsertOp) to insert values in the list of a given entry.

However, I want to update/delete a given list value using the ListSetOp (https://godoc.org/github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-go#ListSetOp) or the ListRemoveOp (https://godoc.org/github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-go#ListRemoveOp)

In order to do this, I need an index. How can I get this index ? Is there a way I can iterate through all the list values and get the index and then perform the update or delete operation ?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have the list called `List`. 
Let us say you want to replace element called `value` with `newItem` 
You can do that like:

```
...

for index, item := range List {
     if item == value {
             List[index] = newItem
     }
}

...
```

In the above snippet, `index` is the index at which element `item` is present. By this way you can also replace element present on the particular index in the list with `value`.

Sample example in playground: https://play.golang.org/p/qOmsY9fbL2

Comment: The question is not about replacing an item inside a slice in Go. The idea behind `ListSetOp` is to replace a single item in the list without writing the whole list back.

Answer (score 2):

As usual, items in the list are indexed by their integer position starting from zero.
Aerospike also supports negative indexing to start backwards from end of list.

[Lists documentation in the Aerospike](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/cdt-list.html):

> Elements are ordered by integer position.

[Lists documentation in the Aerospike's Node.js client](https://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/nodejs/module-aerospike_lists.html):

> List operations support negative indexing. If the index is negative, the resolved index starts backwards from end of list.
>
> Index/Range examples:
>
> - Index 0: First item in list.
> - Index 4: Fifth item in list.
> - Index -1: Last item in list.
> - Index -3: Third to last item in list.

Also mentioned in [Go client source](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-go/blob/dcec4388c832b931227afe511b7f047c6b1b53ce/cdt_list.go#L25).

```
list := []string{“a”, “b”, “c”, “d”, “e”}
bin := aerospike.NewBin("listbin", list)
err := client.PutBins(nil, key, bin)

// to replace “d”:
op := aerospike.ListSetOp(bin.Name, 3, "replaced")
_, err = client.Operate(nil, key, op)
```